# How to display two models in vue having a relationship

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

Hi guys am having some trouble displaying 2 models having a relationship using vue as front end and laravel as my back end

I have this table book

[image: book_table]

this table belongs to author table

[image: author_table]

this is my Book Model in laravel

```
public function project(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
    }
```

this is my laravel controller just a regular return on all the data from this 2 models

```
public function index()
    {
        $authors = Author::get();
        return response()->json([
            "authors" => $authors
        ], 200);

        
        $books = Books::get();
        return response()->json([
            "books" => $books
        ], 200);
    }
```

Now using vuetify v-for i want to display it like this

[image]

How can I achieve it. I don't want to change my database structure if possible

**EDIT**

I have updated my code as suggested.

Controller

```
$books= Book::with('author')->get();
        return response()->json([
           "books" => $books
       ], 200);
```

this is my vue code snippet

```
<v-row dense>
                <v-col cols="4" md="4" sm="12" v-for="item in books" :key="item.id">
                  <v-toolbar color="#1565C0" dark dense>
                    <v-toolbar-title>{{item.author_id.name}}|{{item.author_id.mobile}}</v-toolbar-title>
                  </v-toolbar>
                  <v-card class="mb-5">
                    <v-card-text>
                      <v-chip class="ma-2" outlined label color="#1565C0">{{item.title}}</v-chip>
                    </v-card-text>
                  </v-card>
                </v-col>    
              </v-row>
```

but am getting this output

[image: output]

instead of this

[image: output 2]

Hope someone can point out the issue here

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you have established your relation why don't eager load your relation in the query.

```
public function index(){
 
   $books=Book::with('author')->get();

   return response()->json([
            "books" => $books
        ], 200);
}
```

every book will have the author object embeded.

If what you want is the books written by every author then

```
public function index(){
 
   $authors=Author::with('books')->get();

   return response()->json([
            "authors" => $books
        ], 200);
}
```

then in your vue object

```
for (author in authors){
  for (book in author.books){
  ....
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay,  when I try to render using this code `v-for="item in books" :key="item.id"` it shows every book on a each  what i want is to group the book based on the author id just like the image I attached above.

Comment: I updated my code as per the suggestion but am still not able to get it right.

Comment: Then probably what you want is query the inverse relation and get every author with books. Look my edit above

Answer (score 0):

do this on your Book class

```
public function author(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Author::class);
}
```

and on your controller:

```
public function index(){
  $books=Book::with('author')->get();

  return response()->json([
        "books" => $books
  ], 200);
}
```

Comment: Hi maybe you can help on how to display this using v-for just like the image I had attached above? Thanks

Comment: I updated my code as per the suggestion but am still not able to get it right.

Comment: <v-toolbar-title v-if="item.author">{{item.author.name}}|{{item.author.mobile}}</v-toolbar-title>